# Change query string to first directory using .htaccess - for multi-regional, multilingual website

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I'm having trouble translating example.com...

### **/xx-yy/whatever-directory/**

to

### **/whatever-directory/?country=xx&lang=yy**

Where language is optional and country default is uk.

There are a lot of similar .htaccess questions but I can't seem to find a suitable answer to the above. The main problem I'm having is making it work with "whatever-directory".

__

I'm new to .htaccess and regex so a good explanation would be much appreciated!

This is my first post to Stack Overflow too, so I hope it's appropriately tagged and everything.

Thanks for your time!

---

Final result based on Lucas Willems answer.

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)-([^/.]+)/(.*)$ $3/?country=$1&lang=$2

Comment: Do you want to redirect or rewrite ?

Comment: Sorry, rewrite.

So far I only have this, which goes some of the way:
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-([^-]*)/$ ?country=$1&lang=$2 [L]

Comment: Ok. I'm going to write an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this htaccess code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^-]+)-([^-]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$3/?country=$1&lang=$2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Thing is I need "/whatever-directory/" to literally be whatever directory.

So for example the below would work:
/be-fr/page1/ --> /be-fr/page1/?country=be&lang=fr
Or 
/be-fr/page3/more-directories/ --> /be-fr/page3/more-directories/?country=be&lang=fr

Is that possible?

Comment: Thanks!! Getting there. I'm having trouble with the root though, and urls ending in php files. Do you perhaps know a way I can test the output of the rewrite rule so I can figure out how to do it based on your answer?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you have some errors ? Or how the url is rewrited ?

Comment: No errors but it hasn't rewritten right. I'm trying to use http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/ to figure it out.

Comment: *Think* I have it cracked for my needs at long last!!!

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)-([^/.]+)/(.*)?$ $3?country=$1&lang=$2

Thanks for your help! Couldn't have got anywhere without it.